# Selenium xpath syntax incorrect

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create ajax wait method in Java with Selenium for fetching as many results as defined by configuration.

Here is my method:

```
    /**
     * Wait for WAIT seconds for AJAX data to be loaded.
     * @throws Exception - if thread is interrupted
     */
    public List<WebElement> waitAjaxLoad(By by) throws Exception{
        int ajaxResultsWait = Integer.parseInt(P.getProperty("ajax.results.wait"));
        List<WebElement> resultsLoaded = null;

        do{
            resultsLoaded = driver.findElements(by);
        }while(resultsLoaded.size() < ajaxResultsWait);
        return resultsLoaded;
    }
```

And here is my call:

```
List<WebElement> videoElements = waitAjaxLoad(By.xpath("//div[@id='pageTv']/div[@id='pageTvScroller')]/div[@class='boxInner']/ul/li"));
```

And I get this exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector
>   //div[@id='pageTv']/div[@id='pageTvScroller')]/div[@class='boxInner']/ul/li
>   is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following
>   error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with
>   the xpath expression
>   //div[@id='pageTv']/div[@id='pageTvScroller')]/div[@class='boxInner']/ul/li
>   because of the following error: [Exception... "The expression is not a
>   legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)" 
>   location: ""] Command duration or timeout: 20 milliseconds

Should I wory about XPath expression not being snytax correct, or Selenium can't find that WebElement? This exception is ambiguous to me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple typing error, an unwanted **round bracket** is added in `div[@id='pageTvScroller')]`,so replace

```
 //div[@id='pageTv']/div[@id='pageTvScroller')]/div[@class='boxInner']/ul/li
```

with

```
//div[@id='pageTv']/div[@id='pageTvScroller']/div[@class='boxInner']/ul/li
```

Comment: Truth be told...I was looking at it more than 5 times, and still it didn't catch my eye...;) THank you...